# Use of Metaio SDK after it goes offline on December

Tags: metaio

I am using Metaio SDK on an Android app. I'm aware that Metaio services will be going offline on December, but in my case, i'm only using the SDK for offline display or AR content (it does not use any Metaio channels or web services). But i noticed that Metaio SDK verifies the provided license when it boots up, and does not work if the license cannot be verified. Anyone aware whether it does this verification by contacting the web service ? If it is the case, will the SDK also stop working from December ?

I have contacted Metaio on the same concern and currently waiting for a response. I thought of asking the same here since you guys might also be facing the same issue.

Thanks !

Comment: It is frustrating I am working on project and not sure what future looks like I hope apple comes with clear strategy for developers in future

Comment: Please, let us know if you get any response from Metaio support. Thanks!

Comment: I got a reply from Metaio. The license verification is done offline by the SDK. So existing apps should continue to work as long as they don't use Metaio online services. But if you plan on creating new apps in the future, please generate licenses for them before the service goes offline.

Answer (score 0):

You can login as a developer and download the licence key generator which will make offline apps available past December 15th.

Comment: Where's the license key generator? I didn't noticed it on their site?

Comment: I also couldn't locate this. Could you provide a link ? Thanks !